# Implementing Combobox (Drop down) as part of new DB record

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a local DB, which already has records. I am currently working on a Library Project, and have both Books & Category tables (category being also a FK in books table) in DB.

Within the Windows Forms app, I'm trying to implement a form to insert a new book record in books table, with the use of a combobox when it comes to choosing a Category.

I have tried the below code so far - Pressing save button does generate the details in DB that are given in the form, but the Category value is always NULL (combobox not working).

Can you kindly help me find what I'm missing from the below implementation, please? The below code is a test I made just for one Category ID - Getters&Setters are already implemented.

EDIT for further details below - PLEASE NOTE, I know about and still need to make use of parameterized queries, and I will look into it after I sort this combobox issue.

```
 private void AddBookRecordForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataSource = new List<Category>();

        dataSource.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = '4', CategoryName = "History" });

        cbCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
        cbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        cbCategory.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

---

EDIT:

```
 string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= 
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library 
 System Project.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

string Query = "insert into Books (BookName, BookAuthor, BookAvailabilityQuantity, Price) values ('" + this.txtName.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtAuthor.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtAvailabilityQuantity.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtPrice.Text.Trim() + "');";

SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, DBCon);
SqlDataReader DBReader;

try
{
    DBCon.Open();
    DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("New book record added to the system.", "Library System", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

    while (DBReader.Read())
    {

    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

finally
{
    // *** If you're going to be opening a connection be sure to close it ***
    // *** Finally blocks work well for this ***
    DBCon.Close();

    this.txtName.ResetText();
    this.txtAuthor.ResetText();
    this.txtAvailabilityQuantity.ResetText();
    this.txtPrice.ResetText();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that generates the DB record? What does it do to obtain, and use, the value from cbCategory?

Comment: Anything please Ed? I tried following the below @Edney, but its not working

Comment: Are you saying you want to add Category to the insert query?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Use ExecuteNonQuery for Insert, Update and Delete queries.

Answer (score 1):

The data source can supply the items in the control but selecting a new item will not automatically change the data value in the same way changing the value in a bound text box will. You will need need to manually get the selected value and update the corresponding field in the update record. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966078/combobox-value-is-not-getting-updated-with-new-record-inserted-in-database) post.

```
String Query = "insert into Books (CategoryName, BookName, BookAuthor, BookAvailabilityQuantity, Price) values (
    "'" + cbCategory.Text
    + "','" + this.txtName.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtAuthor.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtAvailabilityQuantity.Text.Trim() 
    + "','" + this.txtPrice.Text.Trim() + "');";
```

Comment: This is false. ComboBoxes can be used in databinding

Comment: @Crowcoder If you read my post I did not say that they cannot be used in data binding. I just said it is one way, as in the data source can supply the items in the control but selecting a new item will not automatically change the data value in the same way changing the value in a bound text box will.

Comment: I mention it because it implied to me that you are saying a combobox cannot participate in two way binding. If I thought that then I think there is a a good chance OP would too. If you make an edit I can un-downvote.